# Set theory: Maximum orders limited items

Tags: c#, sql, set-theory

This is going to sound like a problem for a set theory course, but here goes.

We're a logistics shop suffering seasonal distress (tis the season). Our main pick line is running full-out, but we can open a second, smaller one with a limited number of items. We can put 40 skus or so in the secondary picking location.

The question is, how to select out the highest number of orders with the item limit? I can default to the top 40 skus and the orders with only those skus on them and that'll get us some relief. But I'm wondering if there's a way to optimize better. We can do SQL or C# so either is good for an answer.

Assume a simple structure of orderlines with a quantity and productId grouped on orderId and I'll translate from there...

Comment: This is a computer science problem, not a logistics shop problem.  Using a logistics shop as an analogy is fine, but garbling the question with logistics-shop-only terminology is not increasing your chances of receiving a good answer.

Comment: @MikeNakis The logistics shop isn't an analogy. It's the problem I'm solving. I don't think I'm so specialized that people can't understand the problem, here. I'm open on that, though, so if you have something specific you think is unclear, I'd be happy to alter.

Comment: I know it's the problem you are solving.  What I am trying to say is that it would have (probably) been better to treat it as nothing more than an analogy, for the purpose of wording the question in such a way as to make it easier for people outside of your industry to understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

You want to take stress off your main pick line, and I would assume that you'd choose orders to delegate to the secondary line based on the following criteria:

1. Orders that have any items not available at the secondary line have to be fulfilled by the main line (natch).
2. Orders that have all items available at the secondary line should be fulfilled by the secondary line.

That's obvious, but when choosing which items should be made available at the secondary line, I think there's an additional thing to consider, which is that an order comprising 10 different items is much more time-consuming to fill at the main line than an order comprising 10 of 1 item. (This difference is not so acute at the secondary line, because it's easier to find the items out of a smaller selection).

So, I think you're looking for a set of items that minimizes the *number of types of items* in the orders remaining at the main pick line, rather than just minimizing the number of orders at the main pick line.

I don't have time right now to come up with some code for that, but it's interesting - I may come back to it tomorrow.

Comment: That's an interesting wrinkle and I'd *love* to take that on as well because you're right, pushing large orders with a homogeneous item-set would streamline things even further.